# Changing locale in Android app doesn't change Activity label

Tags: android, android-activity, menu, label, locale

I'm developing app in two languages. Users by choosing in menu what language they want change locale. This works and everything translates but activity label. I tried every method I found on the Internet but nothing seems to work.

This is my onOptionsItemSelected code

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.france) {
        Locale mLocale = new Locale("fr");
        Locale.setDefault(mLocale);
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (!config.locale.equals(mLocale)) {
            config.locale = mLocale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
        }
        finish();
        Intent getOneIntent = new Intent(this, OneActivity.class);
        startActivity(getOneIntent);
    } else if(id==R.id.english){
        Locale mLocale = new Locale("en");
        Locale.setDefault(mLocale);
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (!config.locale.equals(mLocale)) {
            config.locale = mLocale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
        }

        finish();
        Intent getOneIntent= new Intent(this, OneActivity.class);
        startActivity(getOneIntent);

    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. I could "fix" this using `setTitle(getResources.getString(R.string.my_title))` after change Locale language. If you implement Fragment, should call it with `getActivity().setTitle()` I guess. Also, I clean the task with the next method:

`public static void appRestart(Activity activity) {
        Intent i = new Intent(activity.getBaseContext(), MyClass.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        activity.startActivity(i);
}`

I hope it helps...